# Get all users within a role. ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I can get all users like this

```
var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();
```

I can find a role like this

```
var role = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "User");
```

I want to list all users with the role name "User" in the AspNetRoles table (I have `User` and `Admin`).

```
var role = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "User");
var usersInRole = db.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id)).ToList();

return View(usersInRole);
```

I get the role in `var role` but `userInRole` gives me `Count = 0` when I debug. No compile errors.

Answer (score 9):

You can use bellow code for retrieve all users in specific role (Identity 2.x.x):

```
var users = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("RoleName");
```

or for **synchronize** usage:

```
var users = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("RoleName").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var usersInRole = db.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.RoleId == role.Id)).ToList();
```

You search through all the users and returns the ones that fit a specific role id

Comment: Please explain your answer in words too

Comment: Done. Really. Its rather self explanatory

Comment: Please select as answer if this helped

Comment: This gives me an error on `RoleId` in `m.Roles.RoleId` and I can't find `Id` or `RoleId` in VS intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use navigation properties Lazy Loading ?

```
var role = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "User");
var usersInRole = role.Users;
```

Comment: Error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Dignitana.Models.ApplicationUser]'."

Answer (score 0):

you can use Linq expression base query like below :

```
var roleUserIdsQuery=from role in db.Roles 
                where role.Name=="User"
                from user in role.Users
                select user.UserId;
var users=db.Users.Where(u=>roleUserIdsQuery.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Identity 2.0... and .NET Framework 4.5+

Check IdentityConfig.cs to make sure that the role manager is configured correctly.

var roleManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager();

var users = roleManager.FindByName("Administrator").Users.ToList();